# Having problems with my query (apex 4.0)

Tags: join, report, apex

I'm having a problem with trying to get results into my report (apex 4.0).

I want to have the cursist.naam, inschrijving.datum, opleiding.naam and cursus.naam as results

```
 CREATE TABLE ."CURSIST" 
   (    "CURSISTID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAAM" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE), 
    "BSN" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "ADRES" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "WOONPLAATS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(120 BYTE), 
    "GEBDATUM" DATE, 
    "TELNR" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("CURSISTID")


  CREATE TABLE "CURSUS" 
   (    "CURSUSID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAAM" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "OMSCHRIJVING" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "KOSTEN" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "TOTDATUM" DATE, 
    "VANDATUM" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LOKAAL" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "ROOSTERROOSTERID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "OPLEIDINGOPLEIDINGID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 


 CREATE TABLE "INSCHRIJVING" 
   (    "INSCHRIJVINGID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DATUM" DATE, 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "OPLEIDINGOPLEIDINGID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CURSISTCURSISTID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CURSUSCURSUSID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("INSCHRIJVINGID")




CREATE TABLE "OPLEIDING" 
   (    "OPLEIDINGID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAAM" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "KOSTEN" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "OMSCHRIJVING" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "OPLEIDEROPLEIDERID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BEGINDATUM" DATE, 
    "EINDDATUM" DATE, 
    "AANGEMAAKTOP" DATE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("OPLEIDINGID")
```

I have the following query:

```
select cursist.naam, inschrijving.datum, opleiding.naam, cursus.naam
from cursist , inschrijving, opleiding, cursus
WHERE cursist.cursistID = 1
AND inschrijving.CURSISTCURSISTID = cursist.cursistID
AND opleiding.opleidingid = inschrijving.opleidingopleidingid
AND cursus.cursusid = inschrijving.cursuscursusid
```

with the following error:
ORA-20001: Your query contains duplicate alias names, queries used for reports require unique alias names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple result columns with the same name. Try this:

```
select
    cursist.naam AS cursist_naam,
    inschrijving.datum,
    opleiding.naam AS opleiding_naam,
    cursus.naam AS cursus_naam
from
    cursist,
    inschrijving,
    opleiding,
    cursus
WHERE
    cursist.cursistID = 1
    AND inschrijving.CURSISTCURSISTID = cursist.cursistID
    AND opleiding.opleidingid = inschrijving.opleidingopleidingid
    AND cursus.cursusid = inschrijving.cursuscursusid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've used your answer to test it and now it works :D You're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You have several columns called `naam` in your query - you should give them different names. E.g.:

```
SELECT cursist.naam AS cursist_naam, 
       inschrijving.datum, 
       opleiding.naam AS opleiding_naam, 
       cursus.naam AS cursus_naam
FROM   cursist , inschrijving, opleiding, cursus
WHERE  cursist.cursistID = 1 AND 
       inschrijving.CURSISTCURSISTID = cursist.cursistID AND 
       opleiding.opleidingid = inschrijving.opleidingopleidingid AND
       cursus.cursusid = inschrijving.cursuscursusid
```